# Adding a new class to JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe

This is my first Java project so I'm sorry for asking what I'm sure is an obvious answer. I've been searching google and every java book I can get my hands on but some how I'm missing it...

I'm creating a project which includes four internal frames in the first class. I would like each of the internal frames to get its content from other classes (rather than group all the content in the main class. The code looks really sloppy and ends up being a few hundred lines long. Too much for navigation. Should this be a concern or am I being too tedious?).

Anyway, this the GUI from my main class (called Main):

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    frame = new JFrame("Perceptum");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
    desk = new JDesktopPane();
    frame1 = new JInternalFrame("Notepad", true, true, true, true);
    frame1.setBounds(0, 0, 1088, 500);
    frame1.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setVisible(true);

    frame2 = new JInternalFrame("Research", true, true, true, true);
    frame2.setBounds(1089, 0, 265, 670);
    frame2.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame2.setVisible(true);

    frame3 = new JInternalFrame("Share", true, true, true, true);
    frame3.setBounds(790, 500, 300, 170);
    frame3.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame3.setVisible(true);

    frame4 = new JInternalFrame("References", true, true, true, true);
    frame4.setBounds(0, 500, 790, 170);
    frame4.setVisible(true);

    desk.add(frame1);
    desk.add(frame2);
    desk.add(frame3);
    desk.add(frame4);
    frame.add(desk);
    frame.setSize(1370, 730);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I would like to put the classes `Notepad`, `References`, `Research`, and `Share` into frames 1-4. I've tried using:

```
Notepad notes = new Notepad();
frame1.getContentPane().add(notes);
```

also:

```
frame1.setContentPane(notes)
```

and similar variations. This is seriously driving me nuts. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I see that your code repeats the pattern new JInternalFrame(name, true, true, true, true); frame3.setBounds(790, 500, 300, 170); frame3.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout()); frame3.setVisible(true); over and over again. Might be it is what required in the enterprise programming, but you may factor this out in a separate procedure. I would recommend it in codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: How is the Notepad class defined? There is no `getContent()` or `setContent()` method in JInternalFrame. Do you mean `getContentPane()`/`setContentPane()`. What is the code that causes problem, what do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead? I don't even understand if you have a compilation problem or a runtime problem from your question.

Comment: My apologies. I did write getContentPane() and setContentPane(). I'm not sure what the problem is. I set up what I want the main frame and internals to look like and then I try to ask frame1 to show me the class Notepad. The reason I want to do this is because frame1 will hold a text service (thus being called Notepad) which is simple, however frame2 will hold a web browser, frame3 will hold some buttons which show pop up windows and frame4 holds a table much like that of an address book. You can add entries and what-not.

Comment: I thought it would keep things more organized if I put the internal frames content into different classes and called them to the main class

Comment: I still don't know which problem you have (compilation error? runtime problem? which one?), and how Notepad (and the other classes) are defined.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure. Is this what you're asking for?
 public class Notepad extends JFrame 
                               implements ActionListener

Comment: If I enter frame1.add(new Notepad()); or frame1.getContentPane().add(new Notepad()); or Notepad notes = new Notepad(); frame1.getContentPane().add(notes); then my console says:

Comment: Couldn't find file: images/middle.gif
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
 at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JInternalFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
 at Main.createAndShowGUI(Main.java:170)
 at Main.access$0(Main.java:162)

Comment: at Main$1.run(Main.java:37)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try breaking the code for creating each frame into a method that then returns the frame. This breaks up the code into readable parts. You can use a Class per frame but that is overkill unless there is a lot of unique stuff going on in the frame.

```
private JInternalFrame frame1 = null;
```

...

```
private JInternalFrame getFrame1() {
    if (frame1 == null) {
        frame1 = new JInternalFrame("Notepad", true, true, true, true);
        frame1.setBounds(0, 0, 1088, 500);
        frame1.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

        // TODO: Add code to fill in the contents by calling getXxx()
        //  for each major contained component OR just creating all the
        //  minor bits that go inside.

        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }
    return frame1;
}
```

Then in the method you showed in your question use this line:

```
desk.add(getFrame1());
```

Comment: There is a lot of information I have to get into those frames. I understand how to get the frame into the desktop... it's getting the frame to display another class that I'm having trouble with. Frame1 only holds a notepad but frame2 holds a web browser, frame3 has buttons to open pop up windows and frame4 has an addressbook like entry system. It seems to me like too much to put on one class...

Comment: You can make 4 classes that each subclass JInternalFrame and have the code to set them up in the constructor (though I usually put that code in a private init() method that the constructor called, dunno why). But still use the getThisOrThat() methods to build the parts that go into these. That keeps it readable and it will become unwieldy if you do any real program.

Answer (score 0):

JFrame is a top-level component. A main window. You can't add a main window to a JInternalFrame. That's what the stack trace says:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container

It's illegal to add a window to a container.

Notepad and the other classes should extend JPanel, not JFrame. JPanel is a component that you can add to a JInternalFrame.

Lesson to learn: even if an error message makes no sense to you, it contains valuable information. If you don't post it, we don't know what the problem is. Code also contains valuable information. If you don't post it, we don't know what it does.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I will remember to post the error message next time!